# Como crear una contraseña tipo pbkdf2_sha256

Tags: django

Resulta que tengo que habilitar un proyecto el cual dejo un colega anterior pero no me dejo ningún password estos están en  el formato **pbkdf2_sha256**   ¿Como puedo crear una contraseña de este tipo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer de esa manera hay unas cuantas, si lo quieres hacer directamente con python, está la librería hashlib, te dejo el enlace para hacerlo con python:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

si el proyecto está en Django, te dejo otra url de Stackoverflow sobre el mismo tema:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166493/how-to-encrypt-to-django-default-pbkdf2-sha256-encryption